# Displaying Icon Library Assets

Tags: image-display, asset-library

I have a bunch of icons I've placed into an Asset Library. Ultimately, I would like to display them on another page so that people can scan which ones they want to use, then get a URL for the CDN link for the version they want: PNG, JPG, or SVG (some are in JPG not PNG for whatever reason). I have setup the SharePoint Online CDN, so I'm not sure where to go to from here, though. How are most of you handing this kind of DAM for your organization?

At the bare minimum, though, I need to be able to display a PNG image gallery of the icons on another page in an easy-to-view grid format. Would I use the Content Display webpart to pull those into the other page? In general, do most people do it this way, or do you just use your own css? I really just want to find the simplest way, to start.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what version of SP? Sounds like you're using classic pages?

Comment: Yes, we are still using classic pages in this particular library. Though, I am building out a Modern version alongside it that we will eventually fully migrate to. We are using SP Online. So, if you have ideas of how to do this in either Classic or Modern sites, I'd love to hear it. Thanks again!